# Limite entre jornada - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde,

gostaria de fazer uma SQL para controlar o limite da última batida do ponto dos funcionários com a primeira do outro dia, filtrando a quantidade de vezes que o cálculo deu menos que 11 horas por exemplo.

Tenho os dados abaixo, então por exemplo, pegaria o valor da última batida do dia 22 menos a primeira do dia 23 e se a diferença for menor que 11 horas o valor aparece, e assim por diante, em datas seguidas, se a diferença entre datas for maior que 1 ele ignora o cálculo.

```
CHAPA       DATA        BATIDA

005770    | 22/04/2015  | 07:17  

005770    | 22/04/2015  | 11:39  

005770    | 22/04/2015  | 13:02  

005770    | 22/04/2015  | 20:23 

005770    | 23/04/2015  | 07:21  

005770    | 23/04/2015  | 12:59 

005770    | 23/04/2015  | 16:56 

005770    | 24/04/2015  | 07:31

005770    | 24/04/2015  | 11:35

005770    | 24/04/2015  | 13:00

005770    | 24/04/2015  | 17:33
```

Comment: Rafael, você quer saber a diferença de tempo entre uma batida e outra?

Comment: boa tarde Felipe, exato, a diferença entre a ultima batida de uma data por exemplo a do dia 22 e a primeira do dia 23. preciso filtrar os funcionários que tiveram menos de 11 horas de descanso entre os dias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcular a diferença entre as duas datas de forma fiável não é muito fácil, mas podes fazer o seguinte:

```
;with cte as (

  select chapa, 
         data, 
         min(cast(data as datetime) + cast(batida as datetime)) primeira_batida, 
         max(cast(data as datetime) + cast(batida as datetime)) ultima_batida, 
         row_number() over (partition by chapa order by data) rn
  from tbl_registos
  group by chapa, data

)  
select c1.chapa, 
       c1.data, 
       c1.ultima_batida, 
       c2.data, 
       c2.primeira_batida, 
       convert(varchar(3), datediff(mi, c1.ultima_batida, c2.primeira_batida) / 60) + ':' +
          right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datediff(mi, c1.ultima_batida, c2.primeira_batida) % 60), 2) diferenca_horas
from   cte c1
inner join cte c2
   on c2.chapa = c1.chapa
  and c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 
where convert(varchar(3), datediff(mi, c1.ultima_batida, c2.primeira_batida) /60) + ':' +
          right('0' + convert(varchar(2),datediff(mi, c1.ultima_batida, c2.primeira_batida) % 60), 2) 
          < '11:00'
```

Para a uma tabela com os seguintes dados

```
CHAPA       DATA        BATIDA
005770    | 22/04/2015  | 07:17  
005770    | 22/04/2015  | 11:39  
005770    | 22/04/2015  | 13:02  
005770    | 22/04/2015  | 20:23 
005770    | 23/04/2015  | 07:21  
005770    | 23/04/2015  | 12:59 
005770    | 23/04/2015  | 16:56 
005770    | 24/04/2015  | 07:31
005770    | 24/04/2015  | 11:35
005770    | 24/04/2015  | 13:00
005770    | 24/04/2015  | 17:33
```

Este sera o output:

```
chapa     | data        | ultima_batida | data         | primeira_batida | diferenca_horas
005770    | 2015-04-22  | 20:23:00      | 2015-04-23   | 07:21:00        | 10:58
```

Podes verificar o [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e668c2/7).

Isto irá devolver os funcionários que tiverem menos de 11:00 de diferença entre a hora de saída e a hora de entrada (em dois dias consecutivos). Repara que **se a diferença for 11:01 eles não serão mostrados**. Penso que seja isto que queres. Se precisares de alguma explicação, ou ajuste na query, avisa!

Comment: Bruno, deu certo. muito obrigado pela força